# Sensu AWS plugin to get ec2-metrics which are under a load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, graphite, health-monitoring, sensu

I have been trying to write a aws sensu plugin which will get the instance id's of all the healthy instances which are under a load balancer and then get the stats for each of the instances like CPU Utilization Network In and Network Out etc and using graphite and graphane generate graphs.

I was searching the open source plugins in the sensu community, I could not find any. Is it possible write the script or plugin for this. Or anyone has done it before??

Kindly help me out

Comment: Try Collectd. It is stable, light and works out of the box. And amongst others, it also has a `write_graphite` plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe a Sensu-specific plugin exists for this. However, since Sensu can run any Nagios plugin, you could use one of those: [This one](https://github.com/emind-systems/check_elb_instances_health) looks like it would get basic information on how many hosts are healthy. You could also write your own plugin using your language of choice (check out the available [SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#SDKs)) to get more detailed metrics for each of the instances.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin to do the same. It use to work fine then. I have testing on newer version of API. Let me know if you face any problem. I will help to fix the same.